# How do I create a GUI for this? (Video Streaming in UDP Socket Programming)

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter, udp

I would like to add a GUI to my project like a video player but I don't know how to send an opencv window to the GUI code. This is a Video streaming using udp protocol so how can I add a GUI part to this code so that it would look really cool to submit my project.

```
import cv2, imutils, socket
import numpy as np
import time, os
import base64
import threading, wave, pyaudio,pickle,struct
BUFF_SIZE = 65536

BREAK = False
client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
client_socket.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET,socket.SO_RCVBUF,BUFF_SIZE)
host_name = socket.gethostname()
host_ip = '127.0.0.1'#  socket.gethostbyname(host_name)
print(host_ip)
port = 9688
message = b'Hello'

client_socket.sendto(message,(host_ip,port))

def video_stream():
    
    cv2.namedWindow('RECEIVING VIDEO')        
    cv2.moveWindow('RECEIVING VIDEO', 10,360) 
    fps,st,frames_to_count,cnt = (0,0,20,0)
    while True:
        packet,_ = client_socket.recvfrom(BUFF_SIZE)
        data = base64.b64decode(packet,' /')
        npdata = np.fromstring(data,dtype=np.uint8)
    
        frame = cv2.imdecode(npdata,1)
        frame = cv2.putText(frame,'FPS: '+str(fps),(10,40),cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,0.7,(0,0,255),2)
        cv2.imshow("RECEIVING VIDEO",frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
    
        if key == ord('q'):
            client_socket.close()
            os._exit(1)
            break

        if cnt == frames_to_count:
            try:
                fps = round(frames_to_count/(time.time()-st))
                st=time.time()
                cnt=0
            except:
                pass
        cnt+=1
        
            
    client_socket.close()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows() 


def audio_stream():
    
    p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
    CHUNK = 1024
    stream = p.open(format=p.get_format_from_width(2),
                    channels=2,
                    rate=44100,
                    output=True,
                    frames_per_buffer=CHUNK)
                    
    # create socket
    client_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    socket_address = (host_ip,port-1)
    print('server listening at',socket_address)
    client_socket.connect(socket_address) 
    print("CLIENT CONNECTED TO",socket_address)
    data = b""
    payload_size = struct.calcsize("Q")
    while True:
        try:
            while len(data) < payload_size:
                packet = client_socket.recv(4*1024) # 4K
                if not packet: break
                data+=packet
            packed_msg_size = data[:payload_size]
            data = data[payload_size:]
            msg_size = struct.unpack("Q",packed_msg_size)[0]
            while len(data) < msg_size:
                data += client_socket.recv(4*1024)
            frame_data = data[:msg_size]
            data  = data[msg_size:]
            frame = pickle.loads(frame_data)
            stream.write(frame)

        except:
            
            break

    client_socket.close()
    print('Audio closed',BREAK)
    os._exit(1)
    


from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=2) as executor:
    executor.submit(audio_stream)
    executor.submit(video_stream)
```

How to create a GUI for this and How to connect the GUI with this code, I don't know how to link up my project with tkinter
instead of streaming in cv2 I need to go with tkinter GUI based streaming on both the side of the client and server. I don't know anything about tkinter i need little ideas so I can add this to my project.

Comment: welcome. [tour], [ask], [mre]. focus your question. -- OpenCV is not for making GUIs, nor is it for streaming video. it's for computer vision. -- Stack Overflow does not do your class project for you.

Comment: @Adven Akash. Use tkinter then use ScrollText or Text.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot test your code.
You write one `socket` for entire client, but do not duplicated.

```
import cv2, imutils, socket
import numpy as np
import time, os
import base64
import tkinter as tk


root = tk.Tk()
text2 = tk.Text(root, height=50, width=150)
scroll = tk.Scrollbar(root, command=text2.yview )
scroll.config(command=text2.yview)
text2.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
text2.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
scroll.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)

def display_message(data):
    text2.insert(tk.END, data + '\n')
         
#Add this in line 28 
display_message(npdata)


#Rest of the code goes there.

#Do the same for audio_stream() function.
#Then put root.mainloop() at the bottom
```